# How combine Stripe payment library with multiple button chosen by radio button in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments, payment

I'm using Stripe library as my payment option, i'd like to make a simple choose using radio button between multiple buttons , as i saw the stripe's API  there is no option to pass other arguments inside their suggested form.

for example:

```
<form action="/tt-server/rest/billing/subscribe" method="POST">
        <script
                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="pk_test_nz81cav6bbcEP4gxWxp1yFw7"
                data-image="https://storage.googleapis.com/tt-images/company/img_2015111514124193.png"
                data-name="myCompany"
                data-description="Pro Subscription ($400 per month)"
                data-panel-label="Subscribe"
                data-label="Subscribe"
                data-amount="400">
        </script>
    </form>
```

what is the best way to make multiple buttons and to choose between them using simple radio button like:

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel" value="subscribe" checked="checked" />
```

P.S

there is no "submit button" in form , this option is implemented inside Stripe's library.

Any suggestions ?

something like this or more basically :

https://www.formget.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/online-single-product-payment-form.gif

BR,

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass extra input fields inside the form for Checkout. Those will get submitted automatically with the card token.

Your code would look like this:

```
<form action="/tt-server/rest/billing/subscribe" method="POST">
    <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_nz81cav6bbcEP4gxWxp1yFw7"
            data-image="https://storage.googleapis.com/tt-images/company/img_2015111514124193.png"
            data-name="myCompany"
            data-description="Pro Subscription ($400 per month)"
            data-panel-label="Subscribe"
            data-label="Subscribe"
            data-amount="400">
    </script>
    <input type="radio" name="imgsel" value="subscribe" checked="checked" />
</form>
```

Comment: I know , but i want to select using radio button between multiple buttons

Comment: @VitalyTarasiuk: What do you mean "I want to select". To select what?

Comment: @ koopajah , select the button, suppose i have different buttons each button has its payment plan , now i want (the user) to choose  one of them by using radio button and make post request from FORM to the server.   please see the link in my original question , it should not be the same but similar

Comment: @VitalyTarasiuk: Have you tried what I gave you? It will automatically submit your input radio to your server as expected.

Comment: @ koopajah  Yes i tried, the problem is that stripe sent first the FORM to external API (their servers) and return object something like this: {
  "account": {
    "email": "admin@xx.me",
    "phone": "+973255698",
    "card": {
      "last4": "4242",
      "billing_address": null
    }
  },
  "token": {
    "id": "xxx",
    "object": "token",
    "card": {
      "id": "card_qkrh2aYq",
      "tokenization_method": null
    },
    "client_ip": "31.168.23.226",
    "used": false
  }
} , and then the in 2nd request that reach my server , there is no "radio" button values

Comment: there is no "second request" unless you're using Custom Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom but that's definitely not what your question/code does. If you are, can you please edit your question to show explicitly what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script>

$().ready(function(){
    var ActiveStripeHandler= StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: "pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
      locale: "auto",
      token: function(token,args=null) {
        // submit to your server
        console.log(token,args);
      }
    });

    $('#submitButton').on("click", function(e) {  
      var opts= {
                    name: "Stripe.com",
                    description: "Annual",
                    zipCode: true,
                    billingAddres: true,
                    ing: "https://static.company.com/logo.png",
                    locale: "auto",
                    amount: 0
                };

// HERE IS WHERE YOU CHECK THE RADIO BUTTON GROUP 'subscriptionType'

      switch ($(\'input[name=subscriptionType]:checked\').val()){
        case "1":   opts.description="Annual Subscription";
                    opts.amount=42000;
                    ActiveStripeHandler.open(opts);
                    break;

        case "2":   opts.description="Monthly Subscription";
                    opts.amount=4500;
                    ActiveStripeHandler.open(opts);
                    break;

        default:    alert("Sorry there was an error, please contact us for assistance. DISCOUNT CODE: CHKOUTERR_F9A0389A");
                    break;
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {    handler.close();    });     // Close Checkout on page navigation:
});


</script>
```

Basically it amounts to waiting to call `handler.open` and filling in the optional values conditionally. I've renamed `handler` ActiveStripeHandler but its the same as the `handler` variable in Stripe's Checkout examples.

Anyway, call `handler.open` when the submit button is clicked and do a

`switch ($(\'input[name=subscriptionType]:checked\').val()){ ... }`

Where `subscriptionType` is the name of your radio button group. Just change the arguments you're putting into `handler.open` and you'll have it.